# flex mxml multiple layers

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

is it possible to have multiple layers in a flex mxml document?
What I actualy want is a panel with a form in it, but with a movieclip as a background.

What is the best way to implement this?

Using Flex 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so if you choose for absolute layout.